# Phonegap how is it possible to have a "settings" page from the application menu?

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am developing an application for phonegap and discovered that when I press the menu button on my phone, I see an option named "settings".

The option that gets triggered on the debugger when I choose it is the following:

> : D/DroidGap(12793): onMessage(onOptionsItemSelected,Settings)

Is there any possible way to hook that call to a page/parametered query inside the application, something in the lines of "settings.html" or "index.html?page=settings"?

I tried to google around but with no luck. My application just got upgraded to version 2.0, but I do not believe that this matters.

Update:
This is an extract of my current implementation:

```
var onMenuKeyDown;
onMenuKeyDown = function(ev) {
  return $("#mainBox").html(ev.type);
};
document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
```

It seems to change "mainBox"'es inner html to "menubutton" when firing the event on the simulator, but this does not happen when I run it on the actual devise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options.

1) You can listen for "menubutton" events then provide your own html settings page.
2) You can implement a native preferences pane and call it via the AppPreferences plugin.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/06/phongap-android-application-preferences.html

Comment: Will evaluate both and respond, meanwhile reading about it around, I assume you mean this for the first option: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#menubutton In this case, how does the application know which button it is? In documentation it refers to "back" button, not the case for this scenario...

Comment: On Android there are the back, menu and search buttons. We fire events whenever one of them is pressed. You just have to hook in an event listener to the button you want.

Comment: Correct, quite there but not yet. I am examining the first approach and then will re-write the application as native (so will try the second)

Comment: Had time to check option (1) and... thank you. At some point in the future, I might try the second one if time allows (although I am considering going fully native)

Comment: Your post seems to lack a pointer to the code https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/AppPreferences